What AWG wire is suitable to connect PSU to Arduino Mega 2560
I am building a 3D printer and need help on how to connect a 12 V 20 A PSU to my Arduino and what AWG wire to use for it.

This question is similar to: Would a 24 V/20 A PSU damage an Arduino Mega 2560?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I don't understand the question. 0scar's answer already states that an Arduino Mega can take a 12 V input - so what is the problem? Or is the question just (more accurately put) "What AWG wire should I use?"

There's a few assumptions made:

You are using RAMPS
You are factoring in maximum current draw (as one rightly should)
You use copper wires


For a "normal" Arduino Mega and 12 V system
From RAMPS 1.4:

The 11 amps pair is used to power the heated bed. The 5 amps source is used to power the board, the rest of the printer's components and the Arduino board.  Your power supply should be able to deliver 16 amps, is ok if it delivers more.

You could use two different pairs of wires, as one pair only needs to supply 5 A and the other pair 11 A.
$$P=IV$$
$$P=5\times12$$
$$P=60W$$
and,
$$P=IV$$
$$P=11\times12$$
$$P=132W$$
From Calculate cable cross-section - Stecker Express



Cable cross-sections for 24V applications with 3 metre cable length
Power in watts




1.5 mm2
100


3 mm2
200



or



Cable cross-sections standardised in accordance with VDE 0295 for 12 V DC applications
Maximum current in amperes




1.0 mm2
11



So, for the 11 A wire, between 1 and 3 mm2. Which, from Cross Reference AWG to MM2, corresponds to 17 and 12 AWG.
For the 5 A wire, a 1.5 mm2 cross-section would suffice. Which corresponds to 16 AWG.
If you have a 24 V capable Arduino Mega clone and have a 24 V supply powering a modified RAMPS
As per your previous question Would a 24 V/20 A PSU damage an Arduino Mega 2560?, for a 24 V system...
Repeating the above, from RAMPS 1.4:

The 11 amps pair is used to power the heated bed. The 5 amps source is used to power the board, the rest of the printer's components and the Arduino board.  Your power supply should be able to deliver 16 amps, is ok if it delivers more.

For the worst case scenario, the power will be
$$P=IV$$
$$P=16\times24$$
$$P=368W$$
So, assuming that you use pure copper cables/wires, then the cross section recommended for 16 amps is, from Cable Size & Current Rating Chart:



Cross Sectional Area of Conductor (mm2)
Approximate Overall Diameter of Insulated Cable (mm)
Current Rating




(mm2)
(mm)
(A)


--
---
--


1.5
2.9
17.5



From Calculate cable cross-section - Stecker Express



Cable cross-sections for 24V applications with 3 metre cable length
Power in watts




6
400



or



Cable cross-sections standardised in accordance with VDE 0295 for 12 V DC applications
Maximum current in amperes




1.5 mm2
15


2.5 mm2
20



So, let's say between 2.5 and 6 mm (which seems quite a variance, I must admit).
From Cross Reference AWG to MM2, cross-sections of 2.5 - 6 mm2 correspond to 14 and 10 AWG, respectively.

16 Amps is what is rated for use in your house by electricians, so standard electrical wiring could be used, that is 2.5 mm^2

Ah ok, so that is good. However, I assumed that it was a 24V system, and it isn't. Plus there are two different supplies and two different currents, so the wires could be thinner.

Fixed it.. Added 12 V
